# Read first line in a file and append it to first occurrence of the search string and Repeat until EOF

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have a file with following lines in a text file in following format

```
"abc": "xyz",
"qwe": "uva",
"asd": "lkj",
```

And a json file in following format

```
{
    "svn-user-id": "passwd"
    "solution-id": 0,
    "cronos-id": "1",
    "solution-state": "active",
  },
{
    "svn-user-id": "passwd"
    "solution-id": 1,
    "cronos-id": "1",
    "solution-state": "active",
  },
{
    "svn-user-id": "passwd"
    "solution-id": 2,
    "cronos-id": "1",
    "solution-state": "active",
  },
```

Now i want output of json as follows

```
{
        "svn-user-id": "passwd"
        "solution-id": 0,
         "abc": "xyz",
        "cronos-id": "1",
        "solution-state": "active",
      },
    {
        "svn-user-id": "passwd"
        "solution-id": 1,
         "qwe": "uva",
        "cronos-id": "1",
        "solution-state": "active",
      },
    {
        "svn-user-id": "passwd"
        "solution-id": 2,
         "asd": "lkj",
        "cronos-id": "1",
        "solution-state": "active",
      },
```

So how can achieve this using bash?

I've tried with following but it only appends last line of the file.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
file=names.txt #file has list of lines as described above
IFS=$'\n'

for l in `cat $file`
        do
        echo $l 
        sed '/"solution-id": 1,/a \'"$l"'' sample.json # json file as described above
        done
```

Comment: Have a look at `jq` [here](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). Could be pretty useful.

Comment: That's not a valid JSON file, and the format of the first file suggests it was extracted from another JSON file. It may be simpler to start with that original file rather than this particular excerpt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -x
IFS=$'\n'

declare -a names
names=(`cat names.txt`)

for l in `cat sample.json`
do
    echo $l
    echo $l | grep -P -q solution-id
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "    ${names[$i]}"
        let "i+=1"
    fi
done
```

Comment: What if I have more number of occurrences in json file and How do I need to loop the lines in file from starting again.?

Comment: You can get the length of the array with ${#names[@]}. If `$i` gets larger just reset it to zero

Answer (score 1):

you can use `awk` to add these lines.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$0; next} /solution-id/{$0=$0 "\n\t" a[++i]} 1' lines file
```

---

In case the matches in file are more than the lines, above command will print empty lines for the additional matches. In case you need to loop over lines and print a new line for all matches, you have to make `i` restart from the beginning, for example like this:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$0; next} /solution-id/{$0=$0 "\n\t" a[i++%length(a)+1]} 1' lines file
```

---

Note: as already commented, your input is not a valid JSON, probably you have extracted it with **text processing** from a *pretty* JSON file. If you need to treat your initial input as JSON you have to use a **JSON processing** tool.

Answer (score 0):

If your `solution-id` identifiers match the order with your file here is the code that does what you need:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

x=0
cp sample.json tmp.json
while read l
    do
    sed -i "/\"solution-id\": ${x},/a ${l}" tmp.json
    x=$(($x + 1))
    done < names.txt

cat tmp.json
```

It copies your input file and performs sed replacements in place and prints it at the end.

Comment: script is appending only first line to at each occurrence of the search string.
It actually should be like first line at first occurrence, second line at second occurrence, third line at third occurrence and so on....continuing till EOF.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/^/    /' textFile | sed '/solution-id/R /dev/stdin' jsonFile
```

Prepend 4 spaces to each line of the text file and pipe the results to the second invocation of sed which appends the lines (one at a time) to the json file when matching on the string `solution-id`.